# How to return a blank cell when the formula is based on dates

Tags: date, google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a large google spreadsheet that predicts events based on dates of other events based on simple formula e.g.

```
=ArrayFormula(K2:K)+5
```

I simply want the cell to which the formula applies to stay blank if there is no input in the reference cell

I have tried

```
=If((ArrayFormula(K2:K)+5)> 4/1/1900, ArrayFormula(K2:K)+5, " ")
```

but I still get 04/01/1900 displayed in the cells. I try to edit the formula to add the "0" in the month of the date in the formula, but it deletes it and the formula then does not work.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the entire column L in which you want to apply the ARRAYFORMULA, then enter in cell L2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(K2:K),"",K2:K+5))
```

If the values come up numbers, then format column L as dates.

Sample:

[image]

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to you, but yes, this worked Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((K2:K+5)>"4/1/1900", (K2:K+5), ))
```

Comment: Now I get #REF in all the cells, and this error "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in L3."

Comment: Also the simple formula no longer works when I then enter a date in the reference cell

Comment: @McMahok can you share a copy of your sheet?